# ASP.NET WebAPI Service to Service Authentication for services within corp (intranet)

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, jwt

What are the best way for ASP.NET WebAPI Service to Service Authentication for services within corp (intranet)? Certificates, JSON Web Token or OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

I think the right answer depends.  You may get different answers based on what others use.  But the best advice I've heard is to not create your own.  Use a standard that is well documented and stick to that. OAuth is a good one.

Also as far as just providing for corporate purposes, if you can use a good standard then use that.  Sometimes policies and other software make that difficult.  But if your software ever gets pushed outside the company it would be better off using something in existence.